# How to import list Users csv in Django Admin using Django-import-export

Tags: python

I am using django-import-export, and how do I want to import Users from csv. Because in the Document, there are only instructions for self-created models

Comment: you should use csv library to read the csv file and then add users to model

Comment: Please guide in detail.  Thanks

Comment: check the ans if that's what you want

Answer (score 0):

lets say your csv file has list of users and password such that:
users.csv:

```
user1,pass1
user2,pass2
.....
```

adddata.py:

```
from userapp.models import *
import csv
with open('users.csv','rt')as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    for row in data:
        user = User()
        user.username=row[0]
        user.set_password=row[1]
        user.save()
```

Comment: How to run adddata.py ?

Comment: Just run in separately in terminal but in same folder